# Parsing JSON attribute using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization, mknetworkkit

I am stuck on how to parse an attributed JSON object. I manage to parse the JSON object and get a neat `NSDictionary`, however I get attributes as `@"xxx"` texts.. which is not preferable.

I am guessing it has to do with me `options:kNilOptions` but I can't find what it should be.

This is the JSON object:

```
{
    "sport": [
        {
            "@description": "Fotboll",
            "@id": "1",
            "@name": "SOCCER"
        },
        {
            "@description": "Ishockey",
            "@id": "2",
            "@name": "HOCKEY"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my result dictionary:

```
2013-08-26 22:46:44.461 OddsApp[21971:70b] __50-[GetSportsService getSportsOnCompletion:onError:]_block_invoke [Line 43] JSON: 
{
    sport =     (
                {
            "@description" = Fotboll;
            "@id" = 1;
            "@name" = SOCCER;
        },
                {
            "@description" = Ishockey;
            "@id" = 2;
            "@name" = HOCKEY;
        }
    );
}
```

This is my code:

```
-(void)getSportsOnCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *sports))completionBlock onError:(MKNKErrorBlock)errorBlock
{
    [self addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {
        DLog(@"%@: %@", [completedOperation isCachedResponse] ? @"Cache" : @"Response", [completedOperation responseString]);

        NSError *err = nil;
        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[completedOperation responseData]
                                                  options:kNilOptions
                                                    error:&err];
        if(err)
        {
            errorBlock(err);
            return;
        }

        DLog(@"JSON: \n%@", json);

        NSArray *array = [(NSDictionary *)json objectForKey:@"sport"];
        NSMutableArray *sports = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:array.count];

        for(NSDictionary *item in array) {
            [sports addObject:[Sport instanceFromDictionary:item]];
        }

        completionBlock([NSArray arrayWithArray:sports]);
    } errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {
        errorBlock(error);
    }];

    [ApplicationDelegate.networkEngine enqueueOperation:self forceReload:YES];
}
```

What I would like to get as result dictionary:

```
{
    sport =     (
                {
            "description" = Fotboll;
            "id" = 1;
            "name" = SOCCER;
        },
                {
            "description" = Ishockey;
            "id" = 2;
            "name" = HOCKEY;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I meant of course "I would really appreciate some help" in my bounty message.

Comment: The only difference I see between the current and desired put is the `@` at the beginning of the keys, is that correct? or Am i missing something?

Comment: Why should the JSON parser treat the "@" symbol differently than any other character encoded in UTF-8?  Attributes are not a valid extension to JSON, which means you have to do the string manipulation yourself in order to parse the keys your way, or write your own parser.

Comment: @CodaFi I was under the impression that this is how Json shows attributes when parsed from e.g. XML. The json object is returned from a Java-spring service (if I am not misstaken) which has support for different accept types (e.g. XML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser is perfectly fine. You are right, it may be the result of an XML conversion, see for example "[Converting Between XML and JSON](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html)".

If the parser would simply drop the leading '@' there would be no way to convert the JSON back to XML (since the conversion process is designed to be reversible), so you have to access an attribute by `node[@"@name"]` and a child by `node[@"name"]`

If, in the future, the service changes from attributes to nodes you have to adapt your code. But that's true for every format change...

Comment: I find you answer to be the most correct answer, since there is no attribute support in Json, hence no error in `NSJSONSerialization`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON document has two objects, each with three keys that start with a @ character. NSJSONSerialization parses it absolutely correctly and gives you for each object an NSDictionary with three keys, each starting with "@". Doesn't matter what you want, that's what is in the JSON document and that's what you are getting when you parse it.

If you think there shouldn't be @ characters in these keys then talk to whoever is creating the JSON document that you are parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to parse an attributed JSON object. Suppose I have a JSON response like this:

```
{
  "Header": {
    "OriginalMessageID": "12345678",
    "TimeStamp": "2016-05-11T14:48:34.627",
    "Operation": {
      "@attributes": {
        "Data": "PlayerPIN",
        "Operand": "Validate",
        "Success": "Yes"
      }
    }
  },
  "PlayerID": "68700"
}
```

And I want to get the value for the key `@attributes`, then what should we do is:

```
-(void)userLogin {
    dictOfUser = [self getResponse:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://waterview.gaganation.com/members/casinoWebServices/loginWebService.php?playerId=68700&pinNumber=1234"]];

    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[dictOfUser valueForKey:@"Header"]valueForKey:@"Operation"];
    if([[temp[@"@attributes"] valueForKey:@"Success"]isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
        NSLog(@"Login success..!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User Login Failed");
    }
}
```